# Tortoisehg force code review step mandatory

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

our company is using Tortoisehg to push changes to Mercurial repository. I installed Review Board and is able to create code review request, but still can push changes without code review. How make this step mandatory?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `pretxnchangegroup` hook that checks if the commit in question has been reviewed, and if not, aborts the commit.

[This example](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/70953/33654) given in Programmers.SE is quite instructive (adjust to your situation as necessary).